# Can't stop spiders spawning in creeper farm

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I built this creeper farm: [image: creeper farm]

and it’s still spawning spiders. The stone slabs are placed as seen, and in the layer below you can see a test I did with carpets being placed in a 3x3 square pattern, covering each corner, and neither technique has worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way you can fix this. Just about every creeper farm has a chance of spawning a spider or two.